# jQuery - how to post a HTML list (ul, ol) to another page as if it were a form?

Tags: jquery, html

I've made an editable list with elements that can be dragged around using jQuery ui and jeditable.
Now I want to 'post' the the content of the list and save it.
How do I "serialize" the contents of the list?

for instance, if I have the list:

```
<ol id="topics">
    <li><span class="editable">random topic</span></li>
    <li><span class="editable">another topic</span></li>
    <li><span class="editable">third topic</span></li>
</ol>
```

How do I convert it to the string:

```
?topics1=random topic&topic2=...
```

I hope this makes sense.
My goal is to the save the list order and contents by using post.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var data = $('#topics .editable').map(function() {
    return $(this).text();
}).get();
```

Then simply use this array in an AJAX call or serialize it e.g. as JSON and store it in a form field.

Since you want a querystring, have a look at the format generated by `$.param({topics: data})`. It will result in a php-style query string containing an array: `topics[]=abc&topics[]=def`

Since you mentioned you are going to use `$.post`:

```
$.post('url', { topics: data }, function() { /* ... */ });
```

Then, assuming you use PHP on the server-side, you have an array `$_POST['topics']`

---

If you really want `topic1`, etc., use this:

```
var data = {};
$('#topics .editable').each(function(i) {
    data['topic' + (i + 1)] = $(this).text();
});

$.post('url', data);
```

Comment: This sounds good! But I must have missed something. I am getting:
topics%5B%5D=topic+1&topics%5B%5D=topic+2&topics%5B%5D=topic+3
 => So there is "%5B%5D" where you would expect []?

Comment: It is urlencoded. If you plan to use it in a link you need it like that. If you want to put it in a form field or use it for an AJAX call consider serializing it to JSON.

Comment: What I really would like to get is topic0= ... topic1=... topic2=.. I am not sure how to place numbers instead of the []..

Comment: **Why** do you want this? It's array-like information so you should treat it as such.

Comment: I am doing a project with two other friends, and they are using GAE(Python) - the code they wrote expects topicName1 .. 2 .. 3 - I guess I should learn some GAE(Python) and change their code.. your answer was very helpful . :)

Comment: Thanks for the additional help :).. I will figure out how to fix it on the other side another day. This will save me some time. :)